# How to format response of an api

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have custom formatter to modify the final response of an API as below.

```
  getFormatedFilterTuplet(result, filter) {
    return {
      id: _get(result, _toPath(filter.idPath)),
      value: filter.getValue
        ? filter.getValue(result)
        : _get(result, _toPath(filter.valuePath || filter.idPath)),
    };
  }
```

After formatting the response looks like below

```
[
  {
    "id": [
      3
    ],
    "value": "test1"
  },
  {
    "id": [
      1
    ],
    "value": "test2"
  }
]
```

How do we change the existing formatter or write new formatter to get the response as below

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "value": "test1"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "test2"
  }
]
```

Comment: if _get(result, _toPath(filter.idPath)) always gives you a list with length 1 as a result then just take the first value of the list

Comment: What's `_get`, `_toPath`, `result`, `filter`, ...?

Comment: @tector I did not get you, id is coming in an array, I want to format it to get without an array

Comment: to make the point more clear (from tector) `return { id: Array.isArray(idValue) ? idValue[0] : idValue, [...]` as long as you previously stored the id value in the `idValue` variable

Comment: exactly what Diego wrote :)  maybe that should go inside the _get() function anyways..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formatter
If you want to use only 1st id from the response.

```
getFormatedFilterTuplet(result, filter) {
  const idValue = _get(result, _toPath(filter.idPath));
  
  return {
    id: Array.isArray(idValue) ? idValue[0] : idValue,
    value: filter.getValue
      ? filter.getValue(result)
      : _get(result, _toPath(filter.valuePath || filter.idPath)),
  };
}
```